# A computer program for learning addition and multiplication table

Tags: interactive-teaching

The setup: A 10 year old kid who knows addition up to 10+10 but is 3 times as slow with it as the rest of the class (with very low percentage of mistakes though: out of 50 problems only 1 or 2 are done wrong). The kid doesn't know multiplication yet (beyond low numbers like 1,2,3).

Objective: to make the addition and multiplication tables "hardwired" in the brain (in the same sense as most of us have them: given $9\times 4$ we just "see" the answer momentarily without any conscious work).

What I decided to do is to write a simple HTML/javascript application that creates problems and checks the answers for everyday self-practice that runs for a prescribed time after the start button is pushed and then provides the statistics. If the answer is wrong, the problem stays on the screen and the "incorrect" count is advanced by $1$. Otherwise the "solved" count advances and a new problem is generated. Pretty basic stuff really...

At this point the program just picks two random integers $a,b$ in the range $[0,10]$ and creates the $a+b=$ or $(a+b)-b=$ problem independently of the previous ones (for addition/subtraction; the multiplication/division modification is obvious and I actually programmed the switch that allows to train with any combination of +-*/).

The question is whether I can improve upon it. For instance,

a) What if I change independent examples to some other exercise ordering, like having $a$ changing only every 10th time, so that it essentially emulates row by row repetition of the table? Will it facilitate the learning or doesn't it really matter? In principle I can program anything you can describe in words, so even some "adaptive algorithms" are possible.

b) Is there any point in bringing up the whole table to the screen now and then (say, after every incorrect answer) in the hope that together with scanning the particular instance some neighborhood of it will be scanned? (or a part of the table, or whatever).

c) Etcetera

I also see the kid once a week, so if there are some good exercises requiring a human teacher rather than a computer, I'll be interested in hearing about those as well.

So, just share anything that you find worth sharing, be it some formal research or anecdotal evidence. Just make sure that you have something that supports your idea and that you find a satisfactory evidence yourself: I can try random experiments myself without asking anyone :-)

The answer to an obvious question some of you may be eager to ask "Yes, it partially is, but I don't think it changes anything except that more time may be needed to achieve the desired result".

Comment: Unfortunately, you are wasting your time doing something that ends up being of much poorer quality than what has been done ages ago. Look up "Math Blaster". If a child refuses to be motivated to just memorize the multiplication-table by heart, then everything is pointless.

Comment: @user21820 It is of poorer graphic quality, of course, but it allows me way more flexibility in what exactly I'm doing. The child is motivated enough but has some sort of learning disability (that is what I meant by an "obvious question"). There is some progress by now (though, as I predicted, not an extremely fast one) . You are completely right that the answer to my question should be known for ages if the education science is any good at all, but I'm a total ignoramus in these matters. So, since you seem to be more educated, what is the answer? :-) (and yeah, we have talked to teachers).

Comment: Based on your brief description, unless the child has actual impairment of long-term memory formation, the problem in this case is almost surely of motivation. A random exercise sheet may help, but I don't know any child or even adult besides myself who is motivated enough to regularly practice with a boring exercise sheet. But motivation does not imply similar speed of learning; some people just learn more slowly than others. In your case, this child may even be using counting to get the answer so that he/she can avoid doing any memorization work!

Comment: The only way out is to entice the child to **want** to solve the problems faster. And "Math Blaster" does just that, because if you are too slow then you lose the game, simple as that. Furthermore, it has different levels that you can pick from.

Comment: @user21820 I'm not saying that Math Blaster is a bad program. It is quite nice actually. My program also times the process, though it is just the final score that depends on the speed, not that one can lose/win there. However the question remains: if I (or someone else) wants to make the learning process for the multiplication table to be as fast as possible, what is the optimal algorithm for presenting the questions on the training sessions?

Comment: I know you didn't say that "Math Blaster" is a bad idea. What I've been repeatedly trying to say, which you don't seem to be getting, is that you are trying to solve the *wrong* problem. You are trying to find the fastest way for **you** to learn some table. But the real problem you need to solve is how to **motivate a child** to do rote-memorization. And there aren't many ways besides some kind of game that are effective for *that goal*. I don't have any solid data except my own many years of experience in teaching, and that's why I'm not going to post an answer.

Comment: It would also be better if you confirm or deny that the child is using some other means of getting answers than by pure recall from long-term memory. If you confirm it, then my suggestions are more likely to be valuable. If instead you find that the child has clinically measurable impairment in long-term memory formation, then one needs a doctor specializing in dealing with that actual impairment.

Comment: @user21820 As I said, motivation is there. It is not an issue. Doctors are involved too, though it is a slightly different problem than you are suggesting. It is not clear however whether "other means" of getting answers are involved. I would say "occasionally yes", i.e., if you, say, forget 7*8 but remember 7*7, you can do one quick addition of 7 to 49. It slows you down a bit, but I see nothing wrong with that at the initial stages and even encourage it when the alternative is a blank stare at the screen or punching in random numbers. Do you think it makes matters worse?

Comment: @user21820 *"You are trying to find the fastest way for you to learn some table"* Not for me. I know what works *for me* in such cases and that has been implemented. I wonder what works for a normal average person. You are repeatedly saying that the issue is X. I do not really see much of X, but I'm ready to work on X as well. However, the whole efficiency is determined by both X and Y (and possibly some Z and W). I'm asking "How to optimize Y, given X, Z and W?". Normally X dominates and Y provides a difference between one day and one week at most (nothing to really care about). But not here.

Comment: Yes, getting 7×8 from 7×7+7 **is indeed** making matters worse. The right alternative is **not** to blankly stare but simply to look again at the *entire* multiplication-table. (It is crucial to always refer to the same table despite needing only one cell.) Practicing the table is **not** a matter of getting the answer correct **but** getting the answer instantly via recall (literally like a *table-lookup* in CS terms). Anyone with intact memory-formation will eventually have the lookup table in long-term memory, and all one has to do is to keep looking at the table until one remembers it all.

Comment: @user21820 Yep, the option to pop-up the multiplication table is there. I'll encourage using it in such cases then. As I said, I'm just not sure what is the best way to proceed, so I'm looking for a qualified advice while experimenting with some options myself. Thanks for sharing your ideas. If you have something else to add, I'm all ears :-)

Comment: Ah okay I do have something else to add. I believe it might be better to get the student to make *their own* multiplication table and keep referring to that, rather than using whatever you provide to them. Tell him/her to decorate his/her own table however they like. Some people learn faster if they were involved more in making their own learning material. And perhaps consider making the table into an exploration playground; ask the child to find as many patterns as they can to share with you, and tell them a new pattern for every one that they find. For your reference here are some patterns:

Comment: (1) Diagonal symmetry and monotonicity. (2) k×1 = k. (3) k×10 = k++"0". (4) k×{2/4/6/8} ends with an even digit. (5) k×5 ends with 0 if k is even and with 5 otherwise. (6) k×9 has first digit increasing and second digit decreasing. (7) k×8 has first digit increasing and second digit decreasing by 2, except after 40. (8) k×3 has digit sum {3/6/9}. (9) k×4 can be obtained from k×2 for the first half and then the second half is the first half plus 20. (10) Same for k×6 from k×3 except second half is plus 30. (11) k×11 = k++k. (12) k×7 is special because it is not covered by the above patterns.

Comment: @user21820 Yeah, that may be a fun activity :-). I'll, probably, do it when I have an in-person training session. The convenience of having a pop-up multiplication table in the program is that I can trace how often it is used when I'm not watching. We have discussed some patterns already (like "to multiply by 9, it suffice to subtract 1 and add a digit complementing the result to 9", "to multiply an even number by 5, just divide by 2 and add 0", "times 4 is times 2 done twice", and a couple of others, but yeah, a hands-on activity is often better than some pure mind game for kids.

Comment: This sounds familiar. I have a grandchild who is high function autistic and he is very very good at math, working well above his grade level but **slow**. I'm trying to teach him *Test Taking Technique*. He double and triple checks each problem as he does them, as a result he often doesn't finish. I'm trying to convince him to finish first then go back and double check. It's an anathema to his thought process but we're working on it.

Comment: @user21820 OK, it looks like I can finally declare success with my homemade contraption. I used your table advice and a few more tricks (like training and timing certain ranges rather than the full table and other common sense ideas) and now the speed seems to be determined mainly by the reaction time (which should be addressed by a different department), not by the computation time any more. Thanks to you and all others who contributed, but my original general question to math. educators is still open as posed :-)

Comment: @fedja: That's great to hear! Although you don't have an answer to your question as posed, I think nobody will object if you post about your success as a partial answer! =)